# Gmail, IMAP connection broken (server response) (errflg=2)

Tags: php, codeigniter, gmail, imap

I am using whm and using gmail

less secure app enabled for gmail

imap is enabled in gmail

I have the following code in code igniter as a cron job, running every 10 minutes.

```
Filename: cs/cron.php, line number: 237, I have:

$conn = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}Hub Service Updates", "test@test.com", "password", OP_READONLY)  or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
$imc = imap_check($conn);
$totalMessage = $imc->Nmsgs;
```

It gives me this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}Hub Service Updates
Filename: cs/cron.php
Line Number: 237



Cannot connect to Gmail: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response)
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Unknown: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response) (errflg=2)
Filename: Unknown
Line Number: 0
```

I run this script in terminal in the same whm server and it is working. var_dump is able to output correct info.

```
<?php
$conn = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}Hub Service Updates", "test@test.com", "passowrd", OP_READONLY)
or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

$imc = imap_check($conn);

$totalMessage = $imc->Nmsgs;
var_dump($imc);
var_dump($totalMessage);
```

var_dump

```
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
  ["Date"]=>
  string(37) "Wed, 7 Jun 2017 22:16:53 +1000 (AEST)"
  ["Driver"]=>
  string(4) "imap"
  ["Mailbox"]=>
  string(103) "{gmail-imap.l.google.com:993/imap/notls/ssl/readonly/user="test@test.com"}Hub Service Updates"
  ["Nmsgs"]=>
  int(1234)
  ["Recent"]=>
  int(0)
}
int(1234)
```

Comment: Is there a firewall involved?

Comment: Hi max, as you can see the php script above and var_dump. var_dump is able to print correct info. so I assume it is able to get the port 993 of gmail. Assume firewall is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the same as your problem but we also started getting the "connection broken" error message you referred to.

We have a G Suite business account and the email account we were connecting to is managed by that business.  Turns out, logging onto the admin console at admin.google.com and going to that User showed a big red message at the top of the screen:

"Customer's account has exceeded the Gmail bandwidth limit for downloads via IMAP."

It offered the usual "Restore" button, warning that it can only be restored 5 times per year.  We've seen this before when we send too many emails per day and have the account suspended.

Once restored, the PHP imap connection to that mail account succeeded.

[image]